# Getting compilation error in below Soql while checking is won = tru;e

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-marketing-cloud

List OppListWithClosewon = [SELECT id,IsWon,Name,Accountid FROM
Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opplist && Iswon = True];

i am not able find what is the error im making here not able filter this value or is there any specific way that can i go   through or any document any one suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOQL "ands" are exactly that, "AND", not "&&" :)